# App keeps crashing but there aren't any leaks. Using AVFoundation

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, crash, avfoundation

My app keeps crashing after going back and forth between ViewControllers.
I checked leaks and all is ok. When I check allocations I see that everytime I take a picture around 15megs of data pops up (which is the pic) then I go to my next ViewController then return to the CameraViewController and take another picture and that 15megs turns into 30 megs and so forth till it crashes.

It seem to be the taking picture method and this is what it looks like,

```
 AVCaptureConnection *videoConnection = [self.stillImageOutput connectionWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];

if (videoConnection == nil) {
    NSLog (@"no connection");
    return;
}

[self.stillImageOutput captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection:videoConnection
 completionHandler:^(CMSampleBufferRef imageDataSampleBuffer, NSError *error) {

if (imageDataSampleBuffer == NULL) {
         return;
}

NSData *imageData = [AVCaptureStillImageOutput jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation:imageDataSampleBuffer];
     UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];
     self.imageFromCamController = image;  

[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"share" sender:self]; 
}];
```

So I have tried to set the property that stores the image to nil after passing the data but that didn't do anything.

I have a suspicion it is this `CMSampleBufferRef imageDataSampleBuffer` but I am kinda lost on what to do.

Comment: provide crash log.

Comment: Would I get that using instruments?? Cause when the app crashes Xcode doesn't show anything other than a dialogue box that says my phone disconnected.

Comment: you can view log in xcode console.

Comment: Sounds like you have a reference cycle and memory isn't being released. Use Instruments to find the cause.

Comment: your app runs out of memory and the OS kills the app automatically. You can verify the same using the `didRecieveMemoryWarning` delegate method which gets called before the app gets killed. Try using a breakpoint there

Comment: Also, release the CMSampleBufferRef after its use. Try `CMSampleBufferInvalidate(imageDataSampleBuffer);`